# Could not get JMX service URL

Tags: java, apache-camel, jmx, jbossfuse

I'm following JBoss Fuse tooling tutorial and got stuck in [Chapter 7, to trace a message though a route](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/tooling_tutorials/ridertutorialtrace), were you are to trace a message using the JMX Navigator.

When I run the route, the Camel Context doesn't appearin the JMX Navigator. The following shows in the Error Log when I try to connect to a local process: Could not get JMX service URL

```
org.jboss.tools.jmx.jvmmonitor.core.JvmCoreException: Could not get JMX service URL (PID: 10308)
at org.jboss.tools.jmx.jvmmonitor.internal.core.ActiveJvm.initialize(ActiveJvm.java:462)
at org.jboss.tools.jmx.jvmmonitor.internal.core.ActiveJvm.initialize(ActiveJvm.java:445)
at org.jboss.tools.jmx.jvmmonitor.internal.core.ActiveJvm.connect(ActiveJvm.java:233)
at org.jboss.tools.jmx.jvmmonitor.internal.core.ActiveJvm.connect(ActiveJvm.java:213)
at org.jboss.tools.jmx.local.internal.JvmConnectionWrapper.connect(JvmConnectionWrapper.java:118)
at org.jboss.tools.jmx.core.ConnectJob.run(ConnectJob.java:29)
at org.jboss.tools.jmx.ui.internal.actions.DoubleClickAction$1.run(DoubleClickAction.java:71)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Here's the session data:

```
eclipse.buildId=11.1.0.GA-v20171026-1022-B1486
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=es_AR
Framework arguments:  -product com.jboss.devstudio.core.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.jboss.devstudio.core.product
```

I've read this can be happening due to a mismatch in java versions, but I couldn't find any difference in my project, I'm using and building in jdk 1.8.

ny ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try completely uninstalling your IDE and reinstall the JBoss Developer Studio from scratch.

Regards,

Laszlo

Comment: It worked! At first I had problems reinstalling developer studio as the installer I couldn't create some folders. Then I discovered it was McAfee's antivirus forbidding the creation of folders ending in ".scr".

 I disabled the antivirus, installed it with no problems and now I'm able to see JMX's monitoring. Enabling the antivirus again doesn't seem to stop the monitoring.

Answer (score 2):

You should also double check you are using a JDK and not a JRE.

Comment: So far I've tried with jdk1.8.0_151, jre1.8.0_144 and java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1, all throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Using `openjdk-1.8.0.151-1` worked for me. 
Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: Tried to run again with RedHat openjdk-1.8.0.151-1 but throws the same error.